# computed property not reading data initialized in created

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am not sure when computed property (in vue lifecycle) comes. Let's say I have a method that I run in created() as:

```
created () {
  getSomething()
}
```

Inside getSomething() I fetch data and fill my data property as:

```
getSomething(){
 axios.get(...) { this.info = response.data }
}
```

Now, in computed properties, I do:

```
computed: {
  doSomething () {
    this.info.forEach(item => {})
 }
}
```

But, inside my computed I get `forEach` is undefined, as if `this.info` is not an array or has not be filled.

What am I doing wrong? are computed props called before created() or something?

Comment: getSomething should be called with this keyword `this.getSomething()`.
`axios.get()` returns promise, and I guess you initialize the `this.info` on data object already, so data is reactive by default.
And almost forgot, computed property expect something being returned :)

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```js
getSomething(){
 return axios.get(...) { this.info = response.data }
}
```

then you can use the promise returned in created method like this....

```js
created () {
  getSomething().then( () => {
    doSomething()
  }}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could utilise [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/)' state management...

Vuex has :

- Dispatches
- Actions
- Mutations
- Getters

What i am thinking is, on your page load, map an `action` to the store that makes a call to your `axios` service and after it returns, `commit` a mutation that stores the response to the store...
then you can map the state to your component and retrieve the data.

This might not be the quickest answer but if you are expecting to need the response data from the `axios` request, it might be worth putting it into some sort of state management :-)